# Indexing and slicing in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

```
x = np.array([[[1],[2],[3]], [[4],[5],[6]]])
x.shape
(2,3,1)
x[1:3]
array([[[4],
    [5],
    [6]]])
```

I am expecting error in  x[1:4] because index out bound but it gives output how it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> "hi"[1:500]
'i'
```

Python will adjust the end of the slice to match then end of the sequence: there are no more entries at indices 2-499, so it just stops at index 1.

```
>>> "what"[3000:]
''
```

It will also clamp the beginning of the slice to match the end of the sequence: there are no entries at index 3000, so an empty string is returned.

Same with your case: `x[1] == [[4],[5],[6]]]`, but `x[2:3]` is an empty sequence, so you got `[[[4],[5],[6]]]] + []` == `[[[4],[5],[6]]]]`.

Answer (score 1):

For the interval index it is the behavior of Numpy. If you give a single index (out of range) it will raise error. For Example:

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
x[7]
```

If you want to have both raise error and interval indexing  you can use Numpy take:

```
a = [4, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8]
indices = range(3, 7)
np.take(a, indices)
```

in both the above cases, Numpy will raise error